# Notepad++: Replace 10th character if 4th-8th character contains "B490" in a text file

Tags: notepad++

I need to search “FE45” between position 10-31, and then replace character between 3rd-6th to zzzz.

Example file:

```
123AAA345FE45D
234BBB335DDFFFEEDFE45E
345CCC234ERFDF3FR06G
```

My wish :-)

```
123000345FE45D
234000335DDFFFEEDFE45E
345000234ERFDF3FR06G
```

How can I modify this expression to get the above results?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What your expression currently does wrong? Please also post sample data with desired output,  that would help us to better understand your problem.

Comment: Why the third line is replaced? There is no `FE45` between position 10 and 31

Answer (score 1):

Use `()` to create groups you can then reference by their order of appearance

Find:

```
(b490)(.{2})(.{5})
```

Replace:

```
\1\2ZZZZZ
```

Comment: Thanks, Yorik! But I am getting "0 occurrences were replaced."

Comment: check the settings as mentioned in @toto answer. What I posted also works on toto's sample input

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^...\K...(?=.{0,27}FE45)`
- Replace with: `000`
- *check Match case*
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           : beginning of line
...         : 3 any character but newline
\K          : forget what we have seen until this position
...         : 3 any character but newline
(?=         : lookahead, zero length assertion, make sure we have after this position
  .{0,27}   : 0 up to 27 any character but newline
  FE45      : literally FE45
)           : end lookahead
```

**Result for given example:**

```
123000345FE45D
234000335DDFFFEEDFE45E
345CCC234ERFDF3FR06G
```

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question. Below is the example file:
123AAA345FE45D
234BBB335DDFFFEEDFE45E
345CCC234ERFDF3FR06G

My wish :-)

123000345FE45D
234000335DDFFFEEDFE45E
345000234ERFDF3FR06G

Comment: @supertech123: see my edit, is that what you want?